# Execute commands on SSH server using plink.exe in .bat file

Tags: batch-file, ssh, putty, plink

I am very new to batch scripting and have the following in a batch file:

```
echo off
setlocal

SET cluster="cluster"

( 
    cd "C:\path"
    python script.py -nodes %cluster% -type worker -index 1 -batch 64 > log.log 2>&1
) | plink.exe -ssh user@host -pw password 

cd "C:\path2" 
python worker.py -nodes %cluster% -type worker -index 0 -batch 64 > log.log 2>&1
pause
```

However, something's up with:

```
( 
    cd "C:\path"
    python script.py -nodes %cluster% -type worker -index 1 -batch 64 > log.log 2>&1
) | plink.exe -ssh user@host -pw password
```

It does not seem like the python file runs on the remote server (or if it is, the log file is not saving). In addition, plink.exe gives me some weird output-- the below is what I see:

```
Using username "user".
[2J[?25l[m[H

[H]0;c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe[?25h[?25lMicrosoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1377][9X[9C
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
[52X[52C
user@host C:\Users\user>[10X[10C[4;43H]0;Administrator: c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe[?25h
^
```

I also get the above output if I were to `plink.exe -ssh user@host -pw password` on cmd.exe.

However, I am more interested in understanding why the commands

```
cd "C:\path"
python script.py -nodes %cluster% -type worker -index 1 -batch 64 > log.log 2>&1
do not seem to be executed on the server.
```

The commands

```
cd "C:\path2"  
python worker.py -nodes %cluster% -type worker -index 0 -batch 64 > log.log 2>&1
```

seem to work fine as I see a log file being saved. It is the commands when sshing that do not.

Answer (score 1):

To execute commands with Plink, use the [`-m` switch](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-m), that you can use to provide a path to a file with a list of commands to execute:

```
plink.exe user@example.com -pw password -no-antispoof -m c:\local\path\commands.txt
```

Where the `commands.txt` will, in your case, contain:

```
cd "C:\path"
python script.py -nodes %cluster% -type worker -index 1 -batch 64 > log.log 2>&1
```

---

The Plink (`plink.exe`) can also accept the command on its command-line, like:

```
plink.exe user@example.com -pw password -no-antispoof "cd C:\path && python script.py -nodes %cluster% -type worker -index 1 -batch 64 > log.log 2>&1"
```